# Memory Efficiency - Eigen::VectorXd in a loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, eigen, memory-efficient

I have a `Measurement` object that has two `Eigen::VectorXd` members -- one for `position` and the other `velocity`.

Measurements are arranged in a dataset by scans -- i.e., at each timestep, a new scan of measurements is added to the dataset. These types are defined as:

```cpp
typedef std::shared_ptr<Measurement>        MeasurementPtr;
typedef std::vector<MeasurementPtr>         scan_t;
typedef std::vector<scan_t>                 dataset_t;
```

At the beginning of each iteration of my algorithm, I need to apply a new transformation to each measurement. Currently, I have:

```cpp
for (auto scan = dataset_.begin(); scan != dataset_.end(); ++scan)
    for (auto meas = scan->begin(); meas != scan->end(); ++meas) {

        // Transform this measurement to bring it into the same
        // coordinate frame as the current scan
        if (scan != std::prev(dataset_.end())) {
            core::utils::perspective_transform(T_, (*meas)->pos);
            core::utils::perspective_transform(T_, (*meas)->vel);
        }

    }
```

Where `perspective_transform` is defined as

```cpp
void perspective_transform(const Eigen::Projective2d& T, Eigen::VectorXd& pos) {

    pos = (T*pos.homogeneous()).hnormalized();
}
```

Adding this code increases computation time by 40x when I run the algorithm with scans in the dataset with 50 measurements in each scan -- making it rather slow. I believe this is because I have 550 small objects, each with 2 `Eigen` memory writes. I removed the writing of the result to memory and my benchmark shows only a slight decrease -- suggesting that this is a memory-efficiency problem and not a computation bottleneck.

**How can I speed up this computation?** Is there a way to first loop through and create an `Eigen::Matrix` from `Eigen::Map` that I could then do the computation once and have it automatically update the two members of the all the `Measurement` objects?

Comment: Use fixed-size vectors instead of dynamic-size vectors.

Comment: if you may want to share the code for `homogeneous()` and `hnormalized()`, to really pinpoint the root cause.

Comment: @codekaizer `homogeneous()` and `hnormalized()` are both `Eigen` [library methods](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Homogeneous.html)

Comment: @max Using `Eigen::Vector2d` doesn't help significantly.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a vector of shared pointers to represent a scan? (shared pointers of an object only 32 bytes large, sounds fishy). If `scan_t` was a simple `std::vector<std::pair<Eigen::Vector2d, Eigen::Vector2d> > >` (or equivalent), your inner loop could be written with a single Eigen expression (using `Map` and `colwise`). If `Measurement` contains additional members, it should be possible using two expressions.

Comment: You might want to move that `if` statement into the loop declaration, i.e. `for (auto scan = dataset_.begin(); scan != std::prev(dataset_.end()); ++scan)`.  It might be that branch prediction fails for some reason which can make any loop go extremely slow.  Also, did you compile with `-O3 -DNDEBUG`?  Eigen has a lot of assertions and range checks which make your code slower than it is.

Comment: as others hinted to, this is likely due to cache misses since each of your measurements might end up at random places in memory. So besides using `Vector2d` try using a `std::vector<Measurement>` directly. If this helps but you still need to keep `shared_ptr`, consider using an allocator.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rework your data-structures.
Currently you have an array-of-struct (AOS), with a number of indirections.
A structure-of-arrays (SOA) is generally more efficient in memory access.

What about ?:

```
struct Scant_t
{
     Eigen::MatrixXd position;
     Eigen::MatrixXd velocity;
}
```

the `.rowwise()` and `.colwise()` operators might be powerfull enough to do the homogeneous transform, which would save you writing the inner loop.